# Save file name with ( in it on Amazon S3 saves _ instead

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filenames, transloadit

I'm trying to upload an image to my amazon S3 bucket with [transloadit](https://transloadit.com/).
The filename of my image is for example like this: `07062008(001).jpg`

As you can there are 2 '(' in it. And when I check the image on Amazon the filename is `07062008_001_.png`. He changes the `(` in `_` .

I don't think this is a bug in transloadit because when I check the filename where I save it in the database it shows `07062008(001).jpg`.

Anybody had this before and can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146380/what-are-the-restrictions-on-object-ids-in-amazon-s3

Comment: The comment above points to a question about bucket names. This question is about key names, which have different rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be an issue with AWS S3. I created a file with that exact name and uploaded it then downloaded it via the AWS console. The parentheses were left alone, no conversions to underscores at all.

It seems that transloadit is converting those characters, perhaps because part of the work flow passes through code that doesn't allow them. S3 does allow them in key (file) names. It then appears to convert them back to show you and download them.

I don't know the scope of the problem you have to solve, but you can upload files with the AWS console, their command line (CLI) tools, or any of a number of SDKs (including for PHP), and all those methods should preserve file names of the sort you show here.

Comment: Ok, now I just reform the file name before I save it in my database (make sure the ( and ) and .. are gone)