# How to upload an image to Amazon S3 into a folder in ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, amazon-web-services, upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to do it like this:

```
AWS.config(
      :access_key_id => '...', 
      :secret_access_key => '...'
    )
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
key = "#{File.basename(avatar_big)}"
s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => avatar_big_path)
```

This working well for a file, the file is uploaded to the root of the set up bucket.

However, how to upload it into the foloder **photos** that is located in root?

I've tried

```
key = "photos/#{File.basename(avatar_big)}"
```

but this doesn't work.

**EDIT: error message**
[image]

Thank you

Comment: why doesn't this work? do you get an error?

Comment: There's no error, but the images is saved to the root, not to the respective folder.

Comment: capture the return value of `#write` and inspect the public_url property.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as the OP. This is what worked for me:

```
key = "photos/example.jpg"
bucket = s3.buckets[bucket_name]
filepath = Pathname.new("path/to/example.jpg")

o = bucket.objects[key]
o.write(filepath)
```

Something I would check out would be the object key you are trying to use. There's not much documentation on what are the restrictions are (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116450/what-are-valid-s3-key-names-that-can-be-accessed-via-the-s3-rest-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146380/what-are-the-restrictions-on-object-ids-in-amazon-s3)) but the one shown in error message looks suspicious to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the the path in the file key:

```
 s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => "photos/#{avatar_big_path}")
```

Comment: The same unfortunately, the photo goes to the root and not to the directory.